# Find index of object array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm stuck with the code. I actually want to find the index of elements in dataLayer using typescript/javascript.

```
track: { products },
dataLayers: { current: { cart: { items } } }

products?: IProduct[]

export interface IProduct {
    id: string
    quantity?: string
    name?: string
}
items?: ICartItem[]

export interface ICartItem {
    id: string
    brand: string
    name: string
    quantity: number

}
```

**track: { products }**

products have {id,quantity}

**dataLayers: { current: { cart: { items } } }**

items have {id, brand, name, quantity }

Now I want to find the position/index of products, For Example:

Example: *

```
products:{
[{id: 'a123',quantity: '1'},{id:'a345', quantity:'2'}]
}

items:{
[{id: 'a123',brand:'pen',name: 'Reynolds', quantity: '1'}, {id: 'a143',brand:'pencil',name: 'Nataraj', quantity: '3'}, {id: 'a122',brand:'pen',name: 'Parker',quantity: '1'},{id:'a345',brand:'Eraser',name: 'Faber-Castell', quantity:'2'}]
}
```

position of **{id: 'a123',quantity: '1'}** should be 1 and position of **{id:'a345', quantity:'2'}** should be 4

My code looks like below:

I have used map to get id from **products** as shown

```
const id = products.map(product => { return product.id})
```

now I want to find index/position of those products in items.so I tried like below

```
    let position = filter((item: ICartItem) => {
        if(id.includes(item.id)){
            return {id}
        }  
}).findindex(id)
```

i.e.,

```
    const id = products.map(product => { return product.id})
    let position = filter((item: ICartItem) => {
        if(id.includes(item.id)){
            return {id}
        }  
}).findindex(id)
```

but I getting error

Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ICartItem, index: number, obj: ICartItem[]) => unknown'.
  Type 'string[]' provides no match for the signature '(value: ICartItem, index: number, obj: ICartItem[]): unknown'.ts(2345)

an Some help me in finding position/index of the filtered product?

Comment: [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: What is `filter()` (and why does it the same as `.map()`)? What is `ivm`? There's no `.findindex()` only `.findIndex()` which expects a function and not an array.

Answer (score 0):

After `map` you can chain `.indexOf()` to get the Index of the object and `Index` of `a345` would be `3` not `4` because indexes are `zero based` in an array

```js
let items = [{
  id: 'a123',
  brand: 'pen',
  name: 'Reynolds',
  quantity: '1'
}, {
  id: 'a143',
  brand: 'pencil',
  name: 'Nataraj',
  quantity: '3'
}, {
  id: 'a122',
  brand: 'pen',
  name: 'Parker',
  quantity: '1'
}, {
  id: 'a345',
  brand: 'Eraser',
  name: 'Faber-Castell',
  quantity: '2'
}]

let index= items.map(function(e) {
  return e.id;
}).indexOf('a345')

console.log(`Index=${index}`)
console.log(`position= ${index+1}`)
```

Comment: Then just `+1` to the Index

Comment: Actually I want to find the position of the product like, if the index is zero ,then I need a position as 1.

I'm comparing id in products and items. If id in products present in items then I need position of filtered id

Comment: Instead of passing .indexof('a345'), I need to pass variable id.
id should be compared with IProducts and ICartItem.If id of IProducts present in ICartItem,need find the indexof of the object as shown in code snippet in description

Answer (score 0):

You can chain map and indexOf to get result as an array with positions.

```js
const products = [
    { id: 'a123', quantity: '1' },
    { id: 'a345', quantity: '2' },
  ];

const items = [
  { id: 'a123', brand: 'pen', name: 'Reynolds', quantity: '1' },
  { id: 'a143', brand: 'pencil', name: 'Nataraj', quantity: '3' },
  { id: 'a122', brand: 'pen', name: 'Parker', quantity: '1' },
  { id: 'a345', brand: 'Eraser', name: 'Faber-Castell', quantity: '2' },
];

const result = products.map(product => items.map(item => item.id).indexOf(product.id) + 1);
console.log(result)
```

If array with positions needs to return id as well then you can do:

```js
const products = [
        { id: 'a123', quantity: '1' },
        { id: 'a345', quantity: '2' },
      ];

const items = [
  { id: 'a123', brand: 'pen', name: 'Reynolds', quantity: '1' },
  { id: 'a143', brand: 'pencil', name: 'Nataraj', quantity: '3' },
  { id: 'a122', brand: 'pen', name: 'Parker', quantity: '1' },
  { id: 'a345', brand: 'Eraser', name: 'Faber-Castell', quantity: '2' },
];

const result = products.map(product => {
  const id = product.id;
  return {
    id,
    position: items.map(item => item.id).indexOf(id) + 1
  }
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
const ids = products.map( product => product.id);
const positions = items.map( ( item, i ) => {
  if( ids.includes(item.id)){
    return{
      position: i + 1,
      id: item.id
    }
  }
  return null
}).filter(Boolean)

//[ { position: 1, id: 'a123' }, { position: 4, id: 'a345' } ]
```